# Google App Engine (Python): Using multiple forms on a single web page

Tags: python, forms, google-app-engine

I have two forms on a single webpage, the contents of which get stored in two different databases when submitted respectively.

Here's the source code containing the two different forms:

```
<form method = "post">
To:<input type = "text" name = "to"><br>
Amt:<input type = "text" name = "to_amt"> <br>
<input type = "submit">
</form>

<br>

<form method = "post">
By:<input type = "text" name = "by"><br>
Amt:<input type = "text" name = "by_amt"> <br>
<input type = "submit">
</form>
```

Now, how will my concerned handler know which form's post method is invoked when I submit a form from my web page? How can I differentiate between the two forms when I submit the contents of one form in my main.py file?

PS: I don't want to redirect the control of my application to two different URLs depending on the form I submit. Is there any other alternative solution?

Comment: Would it be possible to use AJAX? Or, you could put a hidden field in both of the forms specifying what form it is and then your main.py file can distinguish from there.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with AJAX. And as far as using hidden form fields is concerned, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a hidden field that identifies the submitted form, then branch your code appropriately.

An annotated form:

```
<form method = "post">
    To:<input type = "text" name = "to"><br>
    Amt:<input type = "text" name = "to_amt"> <br>
    <input type = "hidden" name = "form_name" value = "first">
    <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

Then just check in your handler:

```
def post(self):
    if self.request.get('form_name') == 'first':
        # the first form was submitted
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your submit buttons so that they have different text (e.g., "Save" and "Cancel"). Then add a `name` attribute to your submit buttons and use it to get the text on the button.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">Save</button>
```

Then in app engine do this to get the text of the button that was clicked:

```
button = self.request.get("submit")
```

I use a `button` rather than an `input` because the former works for users who automatically translate web pages and the latter does not.

This works for two completely different forms and also works when you have two submit buttons for a single form.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,

```
<input type="hidden" value="form1" />
```

You would put a field like that in each of your forms and then distinguish between them in the main.py accordingly.

Comment: How exactly can I use the distinguishing hidden field values in the main.py?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't have much experience with Google App Engine.